# Bringing fragments to the 'front' on click in sliding pane layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingpanelayout

I have a sliding pane layout with a listview on the left, and a pane with my fragments on the right. When I click the listview items, my fragment correctly loads in the right side pane. The user then needs to slide the pane to bring it to the forefront. I would like the pane to automatically slide to the forefront when the user clicks the listview item, instead of having to manually slide it.

This is where I load my fragment into the side frame. Again, this is working 'correctly', but not with the functionality I am looking for.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_to_be_replaced, fragment)
                        .commit();
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to post code because I think it is an issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be hiding the fragment because the `replace` and `commit` methods should immediately show the fragment. Try this for now, `FragmentTransaction.show()` method.